# How to add event listener to a enum type to check value changed in Unity3D, C#

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, enums

Instead of checking every frame through the Update method, is there any event driven method to check if the value of an Enumerator as changed?

like:

```
public enum States{StateA, StateB,StateC};
States state;

void OnStateChanged(){
//do something..
}
```

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use properties:

```c#
    public enum States{StateA, StateB,StateC}
    private States _state; //this holds the actual value 
    public States State { //this is public and accessible, and should be used to change "State"
        get{ 
            return _state; 
        }
        set{ 
            _state = value;
            Debug.Log("Enum just got changed to: " + _state);
        }
    }
```